# Image Manipulation Discord.js: No Such file or dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, image-manipulation

I am trying to make a Discord Bot with discord.js but every time I try to run the command, it returns with an error saying:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory './background.jpg'`

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Canvas = require('canvas')

module.exports = {
    name: 'level',
    description: 'Level command.',
    execute: async (message, client) => {
        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./background.jpg')
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png')

        message.channel.send(attachment)
    }
}
```

Image of my files and folders:

[image]

Comment: Well for starters are you certain you have a file called background.jpg in the same file directory? Also you could use a try catch block to handle the promise rejection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your image file is in the same folder. Maybe try using absolute paths instead. You could use the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module's [`resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) method to resolve the `__dirname` and the filename into an absolute path. Using it like this will work:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  name: 'level',
  description: 'Level command.',
  execute: async (message, client) => {
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage(
      path.resolve(__dirname, './background.jpg'),
    );
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
      canvas.toBuffer(),
      'image.png',
    );

    message.channel.send(attachment);
  },
};
```